# Obtener los datos de una tabla HTML para guardarlos en una base de datos con PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo una pagina web en la que mediante javascript puedo insertar datos en una tabla HTML, pero ahora lo que necesito es obtener esos datos para guardarlos con PHP en una base de datos MYSQL.

Buscando por internet encontre este codigo:

```js
function GrabarFila() {

  var dgvDetalleFactura = document.getElementById('sampleTbl');

  var TableData = new Array();

  $('#sampleTbl tr').each(function (row, tr) {
    TableData[row] = {
      "IDProducto": $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
      , "NombreProducto": $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
      , "Cantidad": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text()
      , "PrecioVentaSinIV": $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text()

    }
  });
  TableData.shift();

  $.ajax({
    url: '../guardar.php',
    type: 'post',
    data:
    {
      DetalleFactura: TableData,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {

      var len = response.length;

      if (len > 0) {

        alert("Exito");

      }

    }
  });

  return false;
}
```

Pero no me funciona, ya que cuando hago el llamado en mi función me marca error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla:

```html
  <table id="sampleTbl" class=" content-table">

                    <thead>

                        <tr>

                            <th>Rank</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Points</th>
                            <th>Team</th>

                        </tr>

                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        <tr class="fila">

                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>Domenic</td>
                            <td>88.118</td>
                            <td>dcode</td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr class="fila">

                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Sally</td>
                            <td>72.400</td>
                            <td>Students</td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr class="fila">

                            <td>3</td>
                            <td>Esdras</td>
                            <td>42.568</td>
                            <td>Dormin</td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
```

mi boton:

```html
                    <div class="button">

                        <input id="guardar" onclick="GrabarFila()" type=submit value="Ingresar Orden" name="guardar">

                    </div>
```

y esto es lo que tengo en la pagina que se supone que recibe los datos:

```html
<?php

$tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['TableData']);

$tableData = json_decode($tableData,TRUE);

echo $tableData[1]['description'];
?>
```

Me gustaria saber si alguno me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal y como corregirlo o si hay algún otro método de realizar esto.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Tu PHP está mal, tienes:

```
<?php

$tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['TableData']);

$tableData = json_decode($tableData,TRUE);

echo $tableData[1]['description'];
?>
```

Esto es debería ser:

```
$tableData = $_POST['DetalleFactura'];
```

Te coloco un ejemplo completo

```
    $tableData = $_POST['DetalleFactura'];

    if($tableData==null){
        http_response_code(400);
        exit;
    }

    //Ejemplo para buscar el primer item
    $IDProducto = $tableData[0]["IDProducto"];
    $NombreProducto = $tableData[0]["NombreProducto"];
    $Cantidad = $tableData[0]["Cantidad"];
    $PrecioVentaSinIV = $tableData[0]["PrecioVentaSinIV"];

    //Ejemplo que recorre el array y busca cada item
    foreach ($tableData as $item){
        $IDProducto = $item["IDProducto"];
        $NombreProducto = $item["NombreProducto"];
        $Cantidad = $item["Cantidad"];
        $PrecioVentaSinIV =$item["PrecioVentaSinIV"];

    }

//Respuestas posibles
//  echo "Todo bien"; // si en $.ajax es  dataType: 'text',
    echo '{ "resp": "Todo Bien" }'// si en $.ajax es dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Se que no se ve porque aqui no se muestran las lineas de codigo pero el problema me lo marca desde la primera linea, es decir, desde aqui (
$tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['TableData']);), por lo que tengo una pregunta relacionada a esto la cual es: si mi boton esta dentro de un formulario este tiene que llevar el método POST o no es necesario? Es que no lo tiene y no se si ese pueda ser el problema...

Comment: @AlexanderQuinteros Estimado edité toda la respuesta, favor comprueba que esto si te resulta